# Two fair dice are rolled, and the sum is a perfect square and no primes before that. What is the probability that the perfect square is odd?

Tags: probability

> Two fair dices each with faces numbered $1, 2, \cdots , 6$ are rolled together and the sum of the numbers on the faces are noted. This process is repeated till the sum is either a prime number or a perfect square. Suppose the process stops when the sum turns out to be a perfect square (So, no prime number showed up). Find the probability that the perfect square is odd.

Hello!

The given solution to the problem is $4/7$. The solution is very complex, uses multiple events, and uses conditional probability a lot.

However, I had a solution:

> The given number can be $4$ or $9$. The chances of $9$ is $4 / (3 + 4) = 4/7$ because $3$ is the number of times $4$ can show up, and $4$ is the number of times $9$ can show up as sum.

Is my solution correct though (It doesn't seem like it, it uses nothing of what is given in the question)? :/

Thanks

Comment: I don't think it is entirely obvious that the prime business has no impact.  It's unlikely that a square comes up before a prime...after all, $7$ is prime.  Hard to go many tosses without hitting a prime. So, a priori, the fact that you presumably got the square very quickly might be evidence that you got the more likely square.  That has to be ruled out somehow.

Comment: You just want the probability that the final roll is an odd square (i.e., $9$), given that it's a square (i.e., $4$ or $9$).  (Previous rolls don't matter, and so neither does the "prime business".).  Your calculation of that is fine... it's just $(4/36) / (3/36 + 4/36) = 4/(3+4)=4/7.$

Comment: To add to @mjqxxxx's comment: yes, you've correctly noticed that you're just being asked to prove a conditional probability related to a single roll; and since each roll is independent that probability doesn't depend on what happened on previous rolls.

Comment: @mjqxxxx It seems like it was a trick question. Thank you.